Vision - Object Detection (MxNet) with SageMaker and AugmentedManifestFile
I'm trying to create a training job using the prebuilt model Vision - Object Detection (MxNet) with SageMaker and by using the AugmentedManifestFile generated by a labelling job.
Referenced images are in png format stored in a S3.
I splitted the output.manifest file in training.manifest and validation.manifest
training.manifest represents 147 images with its labels like he following:
{
  "source-ref":"s3://bucket/image.png",
  "labelling-job-name":{
    "image_size":[{
      "width":256,
      "height":256,
      "depth":3
    }],
    "annotations":[
      {
        "class_id":0,
        "top":42,
        "left":52,
        "height":35,
        "width":20
      },
      {
        "class_id":0,
        "top":155,
        "left":174,
        "height":17,
        "width":33
      },
      {
        "class_id":0,
        "top":189,
        "left":111,
        "height":12,
        "width":29
      },
      {
        "class_id":0,
        "top":189,
        "left":58,
        "height":15,
        "width":32
      },
      {
        "class_id":0,
        "top":183,
        "left":0,
        "height":14,
        "width":31
      }
    ]
  },
  "labelling-job-name-metadata":{
    "objects":[
      {"confidence":0},
      {"confidence":0},
      {"confidence":0},
      {"confidence":0},
      {"confidence":0}
    ],
    "class-map":{"0":"label1"},
    "type":"groundtruth/object-detection",
    "human-annotated":"yes",
    "creation-date":"2024-08-20T12:51:06.418286",
    "job-name":"labeling-job/labelling-job-name"
  }
}

The field S3 data type has to be AugmentedManifestFile and so the atribtes are source-ref and labelling-job-name
I'm stuck there, only errors then like the last one:
ClientError: Unable to parse record. Please make sure input data is in correct recordio format. , exit code: 2

Thanks !
I tried to change file input mode to file and pipe, add channels like training_annotation and validation_annotation, tried to convert png files to recordio format and retried everything
I found this github but example didn't work for me

Can you provide the code (and parameters) which you used for creating the training job? This example shows how to use augmented manifest files with a training job

@JanoschWoschitz
I followed the following notebook
I found the solution by setting the ContentType as application/x-recordio and RecordIO wrapper
